# c# Setting a Property by the object name from database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a form application which has more than 100 buttons. I query to SQL database to get button name (that matches to the application) and desired Text of it. It's like:

```
Select ButtonName,Text from Table;
```

On the application side, I want to set the Text of the buttons by the result of the query.

Example; If the query returns;

```
b20 Text1
b21 Text2
```

I should set the properties in the application like;

```
b20.Text = "Text1";
b21.Text = "Text2";
```

How to do that?

Comment: You are lacking some key details and perhaps tags.  If `form application` means WinForns, buttons do not have a `Value` property.  `On the application side` implies there is another side and perhaps this is not WinForms at all.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes It's a WindowsForms. You are right, I changed the "Value" to "Text" in the question. I want to set "Text" of the buttons. and "On the application side" means WindowsForm application side which im working with buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are generic ways to find a control.  Presuming that you are using windows forms, the [Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for:

```
string name = "..name from DB..";

Control control = ParentContainer.Controls.Find(name);
if (control != null)
  control.Text = ".. text from DB ..";
```

Comment: How to use "ParentContainer" ? I'm new at C# and never used this before. It says; The name ParentContainer does not exist in the current context.

Comment: ParentContainer is either the form, or a panel or some other control that all of the buttons are grouped within.  Try using the reference to the form class, and I think there is a boolean second parameter to determine whether the operation should be recursive.

Comment: Yes, I used your way and set that boolean parameter to 'true', it works. Thank you.